# LOOPBACK4 npm run docker:start ERROR '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: docker, npm, loopback4

I'm doing the try it out section in loopback4 oficial site:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html

But when i try to execute the next command:

```
npm run docker:start
```

I get the following error:

```
loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.1.1 docker:start C:\Users\jmlascasas\Documents\Laboratorio Hanuman\loopback4-example-shopping
> ./bin/start-dbs.sh

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.1.1 docker:start: `./bin/start-dbs.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.1.1 docker:start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jmlascasas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-27T10_43_56_262Z-debug.log
```

I tried to change the route and searched for answers on google but nothing solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

`npm run docker:start` start a bash script behind the scene if you look into package.json,

```
"docker:start": "./bin/start-dbs.sh",
```

While you are using the window, so might be the case something wrong the script in window. You can try two option

- Run the command in git bash
- Run the command manually without npm

you can run these command which `npm run docker:start` does in pacakge.json

```
  docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:latest
  docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis:latest
```

Comment: If i "Run the command in git bash" I get the same error || If i  manually Run the command:"docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:latest"  -> ERROR ->  'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: So docker is not installed at all, first install docker

Comment: Yes, but what i don't understand is why they don't specify at all that docker must be  installed.

Comment: yes agree. they just mentioned about docker. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback4-example-shopping